# Meaning of いれる in this sentence

Tags: meaning

In the sentence

> まずは、タウラ島に行って、探りをいれてみるか？

What does いれて mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[探りを入れる](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8E%A2%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B) is a set phrase you have to remember. The mental model is secretly putting an (imaginary) spy/camera/probe into somewhere, or putting your hand in someone's pocket to see what's inside.

Comment: Understood! Also, do you know if タウラ has any meaning, or if it's short for anything? In the English version of this game, it gets translated to Windfall.

Comment: @Blake No, it doesn't have any Japanese-specific meaning, and I don't know how it relates to wind. If anything, it sounds like some Hawaiian name to me.